# Conditional independence for a jointly Gaussian Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose $(X_1, \cdots, X_d) \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ is a jointly Gaussian vector.

Let $\Theta = \Sigma^{-1}$ be the inverse correlation matrix, and let $R$ be the partial correlation matrix where $R_{i, j}$ is the partial correlation between $X_i$ and $X_j$ *given* the other variables, which we denote by $X_{-ij}$.

I have been able to show so far that $R_{i, j} = \rho (X_i,X_j|X_{-ij}) = - \frac{\Theta_{ij}}{\sqrt{\Theta_{ii}}\sqrt{\Theta_{jj}}}$ and I have also shown/know that since $X$ is jointly Gaussian, $p(X_i, X_j | X_{-i j})$ is Gaussian as well.

Finally it is easy to see that $X_i \perp X_j | X_{-ij} \implies R_{ij} = 0$ ($\perp$ means independence), and of course $R_{ij} = 0 \iff \Theta_{ij} = 0$.

What I want to show, by combining all of the above facts is:

If $R_{ij} = 0$ then $X_i$ is independent of $X_j$ given $X_{-ij}$, i.e, $X_i \perp X_j | X_{-ij}$.

I have been able to prove all those listed above but am unable to make much headway after this.

Comment: As a general rule, independence does not guarantee conditional independence and vice versa. Do you have any reason to believe that it is different in the case of jointly Gaussian random variables?  Also, jointly Gaussian random variables need not necessarily have an invertible correlation matrix.